# Server localisation support in Android application

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

is there a similar way as iOS application where we can provide server localisation support for android application? if so can someone provide me the idea of implementing this feature in my android application.Thanks in advance.

Comment: we can choose to let Google Play auto-translate your listing details into the languages you support...

Comment: @HarshaVardhan actually we are getting the complete locale string files already from the server and we are able to consume them in our iOS application. now the task is to do or replicate the same functionality in android also.

Comment: You can't do directly, because dynalically u can't create folders like values-dr, values-fr....right? but try adding ur files to database and filesystem. depend upon the user language selection, write ur custom localization class and use it.

Comment: the challenge is all about implementing localisation support from server.if thats not the case i know it how to do it locally.

Comment: I too have to implement this in my project..iOS already did it...